# why UserControl don't use binding and x:Name?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I want to use UserControl such as ContentControl.

example, if CheckButton Check, change isEnalbe Property of Button.

but, dont execute.

why??????

show attached code!

== Window.xaml ==

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4" x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <local:UserControl1 >
      <local:UserControl1.Buttons>
        <Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=CheckBox}" Height="50"/>
        <Button Height="50"/>
      </local:UserControl1.Buttons>
    </local:UserControl1>
    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

== UserControl.xaml ==

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication4.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <StackPanel x:Name="MainStack">
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

== UserControl.xaml.cs ==

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Button> Buttons
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<Button>)GetValue(ButtonsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonsProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Buttons", typeof(ObservableCollection<Button>), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(
                (depObj, args) =>
                {
                    var dep = depObj as UserControl1;
                    var newItem = args.NewValue as ObservableCollection<Button>;
                    newItem.CollectionChanged += dep.ButtonsOnCollectionChanged;
                }));

        private void ButtonsOnCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            switch (args.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    foreach (var newItem in args.NewItems)
                    {
                        var input = newItem as Button;
                        MainStack.Children.Add(input);
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                    MainStack.Children.Clear();
                    break;
            }
        }

        public UserControl1()
        {
            Buttons = new ObservableCollection<Button>();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your Button is nested in custom control and it has no direct access to CheckBox.

Comment: Thanks!
Then, If use checkbox in window, how do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Button is nested in custom control and it has no direct access to CheckBox. Add property to wchich CheckBox binds its IsChecked property

```
   <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
```

and then you can refer to CheckBox's DataContext as follows

```
  <Button IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid} Path=DataContext.IsChecked}" Height="50"/>
```